# I've coded a scroll indicator which works in Microsoft Edge but doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the HTML:

```
 <!--*SCROLL INDICATOR-->
            <div class="progress-container">
                <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
            </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
/* The progress container (grey background) */
    .progress-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 12px;
        background: #ccc;
        position:fixed;
    }

    /* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
    .progress-bar {
        max-height: 12px;
        background: #4caf50;
        width: 0%;
        position:fixed;
    }
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script>
    // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
    window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

    function myFunction() {
        var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
        document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
</script>
```

The expected output is that the scroll indicator appears but in Chrome it doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `max-height` by `height`, I think it will work.
Otherwise, you will have an height of `0` by default because you have no content in your `div`.